# length of data types in database

Tags: sql, database

I was studying sql recently and a question regarding the precision of data types came to my head. Why length of numeric data types are defined by its precision.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why length of numeric data types are defined by its precision.

Because one of the underlying properties of a number is its decimal value, which can vary depending on the application. Some applications require more precision than others. For example, currency values may not need more than 2 decimal places, whereas some floating point arithmetic values may require 8 or 9 places. The precision is driven by the demands of the application.

For defining numeric data types, SQL offers several precision levels using precision and scale values. Knowing the limits of the precision can help optimize space for storage and speed of calculations.

Not all numeric datatypes, such as `Integer` require precision values.